# How to render OBJ model without three.js - WebGL

Tags: javascript, graphics, rendering, webgl

I got computer graphics course. So I want to learn, how to render OBJ model. Of course, I cannot use such `three.js` libs.

Let`s consider model from [webgl-obj-loader](https://github.com/frenchtoast747/webgl-obj-loader).

```
            #   OBJ File Generated by Blender
            #
            ####
            o my_cube.obj
            v 1 1 1
            v -1 1 1
            v -1 -1 1
            v 1 -1 1
            v 1 1 -1
            v -1 1 -1
            v -1 -1 -1
            v 1 -1 -1
            vn 0 0 1
            vn 1 0 0
            vn -1 0 0
            vn 0 0 -1
            vn 0 1 0
            vn 0 -1 0
            f 1//1 2//1 3//1
            f 3//1 4//1 1//1
            f 5//2 1//2 4//2
            f 4//2 8//2 5//2
            f 2//3 6//3 7//3
            f 7//3 3//3 2//3
            f 7//4 8//4 5//4
            f 5//4 6//4 7//4
            f 5//5 6//5 2//5
            f 2//5 1//5 5//5
            f 8//6 4//6 3//6
            f 3//6 7//6 8//6
```

To parse this model is obviously very simple. But I don't know, how to render this.

The author of this lib give some [example](https://github.com/frenchtoast747/webgl-obj-loader#initmeshbuffersgl-mesh), but this code do nothing, when I run it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an example project on a different branch of the webgl-obj-loader:
https://github.com/frenchtoast747/webgl-obj-loader/tree/gh-pages

Of course, the code is tailored to that particular project, but it should give you a good idea of how it can be used within a project.

In that project, there is a helper function in [helpers.js](https://github.com/frenchtoast747/webgl-obj-loader/blob/gh-pages/helpers.js) called `drawObject()`. This is basically what the example is doing. Compare the code in both to try and understand what is going on. (Hint: model is just a JS object that contains a pointer to an `OBJ.mesh` instance and the `OBJ.mesh` has already been initialized by the call to `initMeshBuffers()`).

Without knowing what you've tried and since even the most basic WebGL scripts require a lot of boilerplate code (with a lot of places for things to break), I can't really help out any more than that.

Also, checkout the development branch for the absolute basic setup required to use the loader:
https://github.com/frenchtoast747/webgl-obj-loader/tree/development/development